# Is there anyway to integrate air printing to Xamarin Forms IOS devices

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, printing, xamarin.ios, ios-bluetooth

I am creating an `IOS` app using `Xamarin Forms`. And I need to implement a feature to print documents such as invoices through `Bluetooth printers`. I searched the internet and found some articles and blog posts about implementing the above-mentioned feature on `Android` devices. However, I couldn't find anything about `IOS` implementations. Is it actually possible to implement the above-mentioned feature in `IOS` using `Xamarin Forms`?

Comment: Can you print to a Bluetooth printer using Xamarin iOS?  Yes, but without more detail about what you’re doing it’s difficult to give specific advice

Comment: @Jason I'm developing an ERP system. I want to print the invoices via air-printers (Bluetooth Printers). I want to print a byte array obtained from the API.

Comment: Do you specifically mean using iOS AirPrint?  Or a mobile Bluetooth receipt printer?  Or something else?

Comment: @Jason If integrating IOS AirPrint is Possible, that would be awsome. if not I'm ok with any method.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/ios-samples/printsample/

Comment: @Jason Thanks for the Help. Much Appreciate it!